# MySQL - two counts with different WHERE in one query

Tags: mysql

table

```
field1 field2
a       1
b
c       3
e       4
f
```

I need to count field1 and `not empty field2` with on query:

```
SELECT COUNT(field1) FROM table
+
SELECT COUNT(field2) FROM table WHERE field2 != ''
```

result should be 5 and 3 `in one query`.

Is it possible?

Comment: Do you want 5 *and* 3, or just 8?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Easy as pie :)

```
select count(field1), count(field2)
from my_table
```

Result:

```
+--------+--------+
| field1 | field2 |
+--------+--------+
| 5      | 3      |
+--------+--------+
```

---

If the empty values in the `field2` column are `''` (empty strings) instead of actual `NULL`, you can try this:

```
select count(field1), sum(case when field2 != '' then 1 else 0 end)
from my_table;
```

Comment: That's going to return 5 and 5; `count()` counts any value that isn't NULL, including empty strings

Comment: @Michael Mrozek, yea I noticed he was using `!= ''` in his question and updated my post accordingly.

Answer (score 7):

```
SELECT
    (SELECT COUNT(field1) FROM table) AS count1,
    (SELECT COUNT(field2) FROM table WHERE field2 != '') AS count2
```

Comment: This is my personal favorite for utter simplicity and semi-intuitiveness.

Answer (score 4):

Yet another way:

```
SELECT COUNT(field1), COUNT(IF(field2='', NULL, field2))
    FROM ...
```

Answer (score 0):

to combine the results of queries with identical column formats, use UNION between them

```
SELECT w FROM x
UNION
SELECT y FROM z
```